# Checking for null arrays in an PSObject

Tags: powershell

How would I go about Checking for Null or empty in an Object that has multiple arrays?

```
$buildings.North = {bld1,bld2,bld3}
$buildings.South = {}
$buildings.East = {bld5,bld6}
$buildings.West = {bld7,bld8,bld9,bld10}
```

I started out with a if / elseif to go through each one, but that would be 16 combinations of this:

```
if ($Buildings.North.count -eq "0" -and $Buildings.South.count -ge "1" -and $Buildings.East.count -ge "1" -and $Buildings.West.count -ge "1" ){set-function -OPT1 $Buildings.South -OPT2 $Buildings.East -OPT3 $Buildings.West }
elseif ($Buildings.North.count -ge "1" -and $Buildings.South.count -ge "1" -and $Buildings.East.count -ge "1" -and $Buildings.West.count -ge "1" ){set-function -OPT1 $Buildings.North -OPT2 $Buildings.South -OPT3 $Buildings.East -OPT4 $Buildings.West}
elseif ($Buildings.North.count -eq "0" -and $Buildings.South.count -eq "0" -and $Buildings.East.count -eq "0"  -and $Buildings.West.count -eq "0"){#empty do nothing}
elseif ($Buildings.North.count -eq "0" -and $Buildings.South.count -eq "0" -and $Buildings.East.count -ge "1" -and $Buildings.West.count -ge "1" ){set-function -OPT3 $Buildings.East -OPT4 $Buildings.West}
```

Since you could have hundreds of options in a object, that could be a lot of code. I also tried to build the cmd, out of a string:

```
$cmd = ' -Location $Loc' 
if ($Buildings.North.count -ge "1"){ $cmd += ' -OPT1 $Buildings.North ' }
elseif ($Buildings.South.count -ge "1"){$cmd += ' -OPT2 $Buildings.South'}
elseif ($Buildings.East.count -ge "1"){$cmd += ' -OPT3 $Buildings.East'}
elseif ($Buildings.West.count -ge "1"){$cmd += ' -OPT4 $Buildings.West'}
Set-Function $cmd
```

Not much success with this approach either. There has to be a better way to do this sort of checking, help finding it would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work:

```
$cmd = ' -Location `$Loc' 
if ($Buildings.North.count -ge "1"){ $cmd += ' -OPT1 `$Buildings.North ' }
elseif ($Buildings.South.count -ge "1"){$cmd += ' -OPT2 `$Buildings.South'}
elseif ($Buildings.East.count -ge "1"){$cmd += ' -OPT3 `$Buildings.East'}
elseif ($Buildings.West.count -ge "1"){$cmd += ' -OPT4 `$Buildings.West'}
Invoke-Expression "Set-Function $cmd"
```

Comment: Invoke-Expression! ahh! That works for getting the function to work. Thank you. Do you happen to have any ideas on how to check for null (or not null) in this type of object setup. I'm starting to use objects more and more, and I cannot think of a way to do these sorts of check short of really long if/elseif conditions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Opts = @{
OPT1 = $buildings.North
OPT2 = $buildings.South
OPT3 = $buildings.East
OPT4 = $buildings.West
}

$opts.GetEnumerator() |
foreach {if (-not $_.value){$opts.Remove($_.Name)}}

Set-Function @Opts
```

FWIW

Answer (score 0):

```
#Create Test Object
$buildings = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{'North'=@('a','b');'south'=@('x');'West'=@()}

#Returns arrays that are not 0 in count
$buildings | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | ? {($buildings.($_.name)).count}
```